# Using a variable in an image in fpdf

Tags: php, image, fpdf

I'm having an problem. please bear with me i'm new at this stuff. Here is what's happening. i want to add an image that i uploaded from php. in my php i am giving the image a random name ( giving it an order number ). the upload of the image works fine and i am getting the name i want. my problem comes in when i go to generate an pdf. in my pdf i am requesting that same (order number which i used to generate the name of the image) as a variable from my mysql and if i echo that to the screen it seems to be correct aswell. my problem is when i want to use that variable in an image in my pdf. here is my code.

//this is my order number

```
$pro_forma_number=$_SESSION['orderpro'];
```

//this is the output of the pro_forma_number

```
MAG132
```

// this is the image name

```
MAG132.jpg
```

//this is the image in the pdf

```
$pdf->Image('LALOGO.png',-1,-1,212); 

$pdf->Image('./upload_images/$pro_forma_number.jpg',50,50,10,);
```

the top one works fine but i suspect that is because i am giving it the exact file name.

i know this works if you do this..

// image directory

```
$imagedir=('./upload_images/MAG132.jpg');
```

// pdf image

```
$pdf->Image('$imagedir',50,50,10,);
```

but i have alot of images with different names and i want to invoke only the images related to set order number.

I just want to know is this at all possible or am i trying the impossible?

Comment: Use double quotes `"` and the variable will be interpreted - `"./upload_images/$pro_forma_number.jpg"`

Comment: Please have a look at the [Strings](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) chapter in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 0):

The most readable way using concatenation.

```
$pdf->Image('./upload_images/' . $pro_forma_number . '.jpg',50,50,10,);
```

Or simply switch to double quotes:

```
$pdf->Image("./upload_images/$pro_forma_number.jpg",50,50,10,);
```

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: thanks guys for the quick response ! still having an issue with it. don't think it is related to this question. but i will get back to you as soon as i fix this problem and then check out you suggestions.

Comment: Awesume Cool got it fixed with the double qoute. thanks Guys really helped me out was sruggleing for days on end to fix this and then i finnaly swallowed my pride and asked. was searching all over the place for an answer but no one seemed to be doing the exact same thing. Lol didn't think it would be as simple as a "" doulbe quote. thanks again. see soon

Comment: Remember to vote up and accept the answer to keep them coming in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem when using a variable for the file path is the page break, which is added at the end. A solution for this problem could be:

```
$image="path/folder/file.jpg";
$imageClean = preg_replace("[\n|\r|\n\r]", "", $image);
```

Results:

```
echo $image; 
     "path/folder/file.jpg\n"

echo $imageClean; 
     "path/folder/file.jpg"
```